# How to modify this SQL Query to show the percentage of participation in the last sending quiz in each division in the company?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query that shows the number of participants in the last sending quiz in each division. I want to keep it as it is but instead of showing the number of participants, I want to show the percentage of participation in the last sending quiz.

For your information, I have the following database design:

- **Employee** table: `Username, Name, Job, DivisionCode`
- **Division** table: `SapCode, DivisionName`
- **Quiz** table: `QuizID, Title, Description, IsSent`
- **UserQuiz** table: `UserQuizID, Score, DateTimeComplete, QuizID, Username`

NOTE: The first attribute in each table is the primary key.

`IsSent` is a flag used to determine which quiz is sent to the users and which one is not.

So how to modify this query to show the percentage of participation?

SQL query:

```
SELECT     
    dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.UserQuiz.Username) AS [Number of Participants], 
    dbo.Quiz.QuizID
FROM
    dbo.Divisions 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.employee ON dbo.Divisions.SapCode = dbo.employee.DivisionCode 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.UserQuiz ON dbo.employee.Username = dbo.UserQuiz.Username 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Quiz ON dbo.UserQuiz.QuizID = dbo.Quiz.QuizID
WHERE     
    [Quiz].[QuizID] = (SELECT MAX([QuizID]) FROM dbo.Quiz WHERE (IsSent = 1))
GROUP BY 
    dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut, dbo.Quiz.QuizID
```

Database Schema:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Divisions]    Script Date: 03/07/2012 15:48:13 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Divisions](
    [SapCode] [float] NOT NULL,
    [DivisionShortcut] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [DivisionName] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Divisions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SapCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Quiz]    Script Date: 03/07/2012 15:48:13 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Quiz](
    [QuizID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [IsSent] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Quiz] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [QuizID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[employee]    Script Date: 03/07/2012 15:48:13 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[employee](
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Username] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [JobTitle] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [BadgeNo] [float] NOT NULL,
    [EmpOrgType] [float] NOT NULL,
    [DivisionCode] [float] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_employee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Username] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[UserQuiz]    Script Date: 03/07/2012 15:48:13 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserQuiz](
    [UserQuizID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [QuizID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateTimeComplete] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [Score] [float] NOT NULL,
    [Username] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserQuiz] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserQuizID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_Quiz_IsSent]    Script Date: 03/07/2012 15:48:13 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Quiz] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Quiz_IsSent]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsSent]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_employee_Divisions]    Script Date: 03/07/2012 15:48:13 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[employee]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_employee_Divisions] FOREIGN KEY([DivisionCode])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Divisions] ([SapCode])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[employee] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_employee_Divisions]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_UserQuiz_employee]    Script Date: 03/07/2012 15:48:13 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserQuiz]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_UserQuiz_employee] FOREIGN KEY([Username])
REFERENCES [dbo].[employee] ([Username])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserQuiz] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_UserQuiz_employee]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_UserQuiz_Quiz]    Script Date: 03/07/2012 15:48:13 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserQuiz]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_UserQuiz_Quiz] FOREIGN KEY([QuizID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Quiz] ([QuizID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserQuiz] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_UserQuiz_Quiz]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming participation is as a percentage of total users, try:

```
SELECT     dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut, 
           COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.UserQuiz.Username) AS [Number of Participants], 
           COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.UserQuiz.Username) * 100 
                   / MAX([AllUsers].[UserCount]) AS [Percent Participation], 
           dbo.Quiz.QuizID
FROM       (SELECT COUNT(*) [UserCount] from dbo.employee) as [AllUsers]
CROSS JOIN dbo.Divisions 
INNER JOIN dbo.employee 
        ON dbo.Divisions.SapCode = dbo.employee.DivisionCode 
INNER JOIN dbo.UserQuiz
        ON dbo.employee.Username = dbo.UserQuiz.Username 
INNER JOIN dbo.Quiz
        ON dbo.UserQuiz.QuizID = dbo.Quiz.QuizID
WHERE   [Quiz].[QuizID] = (SELECT MAX([QuizID]) FROM dbo.Quiz WHERE (IsSent = 1))
GROUP BY dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut, dbo.Quiz.QuizID
```

EDIT: Allowing for users to be able to answer a quiz more than once, you should be able to run the following query to return the participation as a percentage of users at the departmental level:

```
SELECT     DivisionShortcut, 
           MAX(NumberParticipants) - MAX(NullParticipant) AS [Number of Participants], 
           (MAX(NumberParticipants) - MAX(NullParticipant)) * 100 
                  / MAX(DivisionEmployees) AS [Percent Participation], 
           MAX(LatestQuiz) AS LatestQuiz
FROM
(SELECT     D.DivisionShortcut, 
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY D.DivisionShortcut ORDER BY UQ.Username) 
                  AS NumberParticipants,
            CASE WHEN UQ.Username IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NullParticipant,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY D.DivisionShortcut ORDER BY E.Username) 
                  AS DivisionEmployees,
            LQ.LatestQuiz
 FROM       (SELECT MAX([QuizID]) AS LatestQuiz FROM dbo.Quiz WHERE (IsSent = 1)) AS LQ
 CROSS JOIN dbo.Divisions AS D
 INNER JOIN dbo.employee AS E
         ON D.SapCode = E.DivisionCode 
 LEFT JOIN  dbo.UserQuiz AS UQ
         ON E.Username = UQ.Username AND LQ.LatestQuiz = UQ.QuizID) AS SQ
GROUP BY DivisionShortcut
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I got the following errors in the SQLServer Management Studio: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.

Comment: Besides that, let me clarify my thought about calculating percentage and correct me if I am wrong. Let us assume that Division A has 40 employees and the participants in the last sending quiz is 20. Then the percentage of participation will be 20/40. Am I right?

Comment: @AliAhmed: Can you add the CREATE TABLE scripts for each of your tables to your question? In answer to your comment, yes, if that's how you want to calculate it - obviously, the query will need to be amended.

Comment: I already added the script. Could you please have a look at it?

Comment: @AliAhmed: I have added a new query that should derive the participation as a percentage of users at the departmental level. Both the new query and the previous query run without errors against the table structures included in the question in SQLServer 2008 R2, both on my local instance and on http://sqlfiddle.com/ .

Comment: @AliAhmed: Where can you find what? The queries are both in my answer, while you can click on the hyperlinks to http://sqlfiddle.com/ in either this or my previous comment. (Just to check: are you using SQLServer 2008 r2, as tagged in your question?)

Comment: When I clicked on the link, I just be directed to the website and there is no Queries there. But I found your edited query here and there is a problem. The participants can participate in the Quiz more than one time. Therefore, I should use DISTINCT and when I used it I got errors. So how to modify this query to count the number of unique participants in the quiz.

Comment: @AliAhmed: SQLServer doesn't allow the use of the `OVER` clause with `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`. I have amended the query to make use of `DENSE_RANK` as a workaround, although it is probably less apparent what the query is doing. SQLFiddle is a site that allows you test queries against different databases; you need to copy and paste the DDL and query code in to the relevant panes, in order to test it.

Comment: It works well. Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help. I need now to go through it and understand it very well. Thanks again dude and please keep your efforts

Answer (score 0):

For example total number of participants are 50 then you query should be this way:

```
SELECT     dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut, (COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.UserQuiz.Username)/50)*100 AS [Percentage of Participarion], dbo.Quiz.QuizID
FROM         dbo.Divisions INNER JOIN
                      dbo.employee ON dbo.Divisions.SapCode = dbo.employee.DivisionCode INNER JOIN
                      dbo.UserQuiz ON dbo.employee.Username = dbo.UserQuiz.Username INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Quiz ON dbo.UserQuiz.QuizID = dbo.Quiz.QuizID
WHERE     [Quiz].[QuizID] = (SELECT MAX([QuizID]) FROM dbo.Quiz WHERE (IsSent = 1))
GROUP BY dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut, dbo.Quiz.QuizID
```

Comment: I think you did not understand me. The query should calculate total number of employees in the division and then divide the total number of participants which will be (COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.UserQuiz.Username)) over the total number of employees in that division.

Answer (score 0):

If not all employees participate in the quiz, then I assume the non-participants dont have an entry in the UserQuiz table.  You will need a LEFT OUTER JOIN on employee to userQuiz.  This way you get all employees and only the quiz results for participating employees.

Then get the Count of all DISTINCT employee names from Employee - this is 100% of the employees, then get Count of DISTINCT UserQuiz.Username - and work it out as a percentage of all employees.  This will give you the percentage of employees participating in the quiz

Comment: Could you please provide me with the Query? I know that I need to count all the employees in each division from Employee Table and I don't know how to add it to above query